Here maps Qt app - Failed to read here/nokia map version. - QGeoTileRequestManager: Last error message was: 'Host requires authentication'
When using here maps that I want to use in my qt application, I get this error and the screen does not come up. how can i solve it


My QML Code
import QtQuick 2.15
    import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
    import QtQuick.Window 2.15
    // Here Maps import
    import QtLocation 5.15
    import QtPositioning 5.15
    
    Window {
        visible: true
        width: 640
        height: 480
        title: qsTr("Here Maps Example")
    
    
    
        Plugin {
            id: hereMaps
            name: "here"
    
            // Your HERE API key
    
            PluginParameter {
                name: "here.app_id"
                value: "e--------------tU"
            }
    
            PluginParameter {
                name: "here.token"
                value: "KS---------------0w"
            }
        }
    
        Map {
            anchors.fill: parent
            plugin: hereMaps
            center: QtPositioning.coordinate(38.4501, 27.1777)
            zoomLevel: 14
        }
    }

my Errors
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
No proxy parameter specified.
Failed to read here/nokia map version.
    QGeoTileRequestManager: Failed to fetch tile (9430,6293,14) 5 times, giving up. Last error message was: 'Host requires authentication'
QGeoTileRequestManager: Failed to fetch tile (9430,6292,14) 5 times, giving up. Last error message was: 'Host requires authentication'
QGeoTileRequestManager: Failed to fetch tile (9429,6292,14) 5 times, giving up. Last error message was: 'Host requires authentication'
QGeoTileRequestManager: Failed to fetch tile (9427,6293,14) 5 times, giving up. Last error message was: 'Host requires authentication'
QGeoTileRequestManager: Failed to fetch tile (9429,6293,14) 5 times, giving up. Last error message was: 'Host requires authentication'
QGeoTileRequestManager: Failed to fetch tile (9428,6292,14) 5 times, giving up. Last error message was: 'Host requires authentication'
QGeoTileRequestManager: Failed to fetch tile (9429,6294,14) 5 times, giving up. Last error message was: 'Host requires authentication'
QGeoTileRequestManager: Failed to fetch tile (9427,6294,14) 5 times, giving up. Last error message was: 'Host requires authentication'
QGeoTileRequestManager: Failed to fetch tile (9430,6294,14) 5 times, giving up. Last error message was: 'Host requires authentication'
QGeoTileRequestManager: Failed to fetch tile (9428,6293,14) 5 times, giving up. Last error message was: 'Host requires authentication'
QGeoTileRequestManager: Failed to fetch tile (9427,6292,14) 5 times, giving up. Last error message was: 'Host requires authentication'

in this way https://maps.hereapi.com/v3/base/mc/11/1100/672/jpeg?style=satellite.day&apiKey={My api key} when I try to take an image I can get the image and I can show it as an image in my qt application but it needs to have a dynamic map.

You seem to be using app_id and token as per the config file, instead of apiKey. apiKey for your app can be generated by login into their platform.

https://www.here.com/docs/bundle/map-image-developer-guide-v3/page/topics/quickstart.html#get-an-api-key - refer this.

May I ask what is your use case for the map?

@kiner_shah hello first of all, for the first question you asked, I looked and did it from here, it does not say here that I need to write the api key [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/location-plugin-here.html]

I did the requirements in the link you posted but it does not say that I need to enter any api key from qt

I was going to show a map in a vehicle display application that I will make in my school and I thought there should be here maps @kiner_shah

There is HERE Maps API for Javascript. Maybe you can use something like QWebView and open a webpage that will use that api and fetch the map. Maybe that helps for your use case.

It looks like the 5.15.2 version of QtPositioning passes the token and application ID as query parameters:
    if (!m_token.isEmpty() && !m_applicationId.isEmpty()) { // TODO: remove the if
        requestString += "?token=";
        requestString += m_token;

        requestString += "&app_id=";
        requestString += m_applicationId;
    }

All the authentication methods I found on the HERE API documentation require the token in the headers:
Authorization: Bearer <token>

You will have to modify the code to do so.

Yes either generate a token based on OAuth2.0 credentials (https://www.here.com/docs/bundle/identity-and-access-management-developer-guide/page/topics/plat-token.html) or use apiKey (https://www.here.com/docs/bundle/map-image-developer-guide-v3/page/topics/quickstart.html#get-an-api-key). apiKey can be a bit straightforward I guess.

Depending on the context, OP might want to prefer short-lived OAuth tokens over permanent API keys. Embedding API keys into application binaries is a recipe for headaches.

It seems HERE map image API v3 supports only API keys as per https://www.here.com/docs/bundle/map-image-migration-guide-v3/page/README.html#authentication-method.

Good find! QtPositioning hardcodes v2.1 in the request URL, however.

I was looking at the URL provided by OP in the question i.e. https://maps.hereapi.com/v3/base/mc/11/1100/672/jpeg?style=satellite.day&apiKey={My api key}

Ah, fair enough.

@kiner_shah using this url, it gives me the map as a region as a small image, but since I wanted a dynamic map, this did not seem like a suitable solution for me.

@Botje I don't understand where to write your code

I did not provide a fix at all. I was pinpointing where in the QtPositioning code the problem is. You need to download the source code to the appropriate version and fix it to pass an apiKey parameter instead
